# Remove element from outside its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an election simulator. I have a form field and a link to add more fields. Whatever I write in the fields shows up below the fields. When I click on "Remove" it removes the form field but not it's corresponding text below. This is what I want to fix.

html

```
    <h2><a href="#" id="addParty">Add new party</a></h2>
<div id="partiesDiv">
    <p>
        <label for="parties"><input type="text" id="party" size="20" name="party" value="" placeholder="Party name" onkeyup="updateTxt('party','txt');"></label>
    </p>
</div>
<div id="text">
    <p>
        <span id="txt"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
    var partyDiv = $('#partiesDiv');
    var textDiv = $('#text');
    var i = $('#partiesDiv p').size() + 1;

    $('#addParty').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="parties"><input type="text" id="party_' + i +'" size="20" name="party" value="" placeholder="Party name" onkeyup="updateTxt(\'party_' + i +'\',\'txt' + i +'\');"/></label> <a href="#" id="remParty">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(partyDiv);
            $('<p><span id="txt' + i +'"></span></p>').appendTo(textDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remParty').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});


function updateTxt(field,toField){
var field = document.getElementById(field);
var toField = document.getElementById(toField);
toField.innerHTML=field.value;
}
```

When I've added a few fields the html looks like this:

```
<div id="partiesDiv">
    <p>
        <label for="parties"><input type="text" id="party" size="20" name="party"
         value="" placeholder="Party name" onkeyup="updateTxt('party','txt');">
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="parties"><input type="text" id="party_2" size="20" name="party"
         value="" placeholder="Party name" onkeyup="updateTxt('party','txt');">
        </label> <a href="#" class="remParty">Remove</a> <--- WHEN I CLICK HERE
    </p>
</div>
<div id="text">
    <p>
        <span id="txt"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span id="txt2"></span>
    </p> <--- I WANT THIS <p> TO BE REMOVED
</div>
```

What I'm guessing is that I should add a line below `$(this).parents('p').remove();` that removes the `p` within `div id="text"`. The problem is that I don't know how to make it know which p to remove.

I'm new to `JavaScript` and this might be over my head, so please let me know if I should clarify anything!
Thanks

Comment: Use `on('click', function(){})`, instead of live. Also your `label`'s `for` attribute should be `for="party"` instead of `for="parties"`.

Comment: on click will not work as the link is appended after the initialization logic!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the closest

element to the parent element of your field by using this code:

```
$(this).parent.closest('p').remove();
```

Here is more you can read about 'closest' method http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: nice copy! but what is the `parents` ? :)

Answer (score 0):

My not so pretty solution:

```
$('#addParty').live('click', function() {
        $('<p><label for="party"><input type="text" id="party_' + i +'" size="20"
        name="party" value="" placeholder="Skriv partinamn" 
        onkeyup="updateTxt(\'party_' + i +'\',\'txt' + i +'\');"/></label> 

        <a href="#" *****class="remParty' + i +'"*****>Remove</a></p>')

        .appendTo(partyDiv);
        $('<p><span id="txt' + i +'"></span></p>').appendTo(textDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });
```

So that the `class="remParty"` gets `i` appended to it for every new field that is created.

Then I just add

```
$('.remParty2').live('click', function() { $(this).parents('p').remove();
$("p:has(#txt2)").remove(); if(i==2){i--;} return false; });
```

as many times as I want the maximum number of parties allowed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you have to update your jquery methods.

The `.size()` method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the `.length` property instead.

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Use `.closest()` to call the closest parent, as the `<p>` tag you want.

Remember to use a class `'.remParty'` instead of an id `'#remParty'`, because if you have more than one element with the same id it will not work.

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/EhjM7/

I rewrited it for you:

```
$(function() {
    var i = $('#partiesDiv p').length + 1;

    $(document).on('click','#addParty',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#partiesDiv').append('<p><label for="parties"><input type="text" id="party_' + i +'" size="20" name="party" value="" placeholder="Party name" onkeyup="updateTxt(\'party_' + i +'\',\'txt' + i +'\');"/></label> <a href="#" class="remParty">Remove</a></p>');
       $('#text').append('<p><span id="txt' + i +'"></span></p>');
       i++;
       return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click','.remParty',function(){ 
        $(this).closest('p').remove();
        i--;
        return false;
    });
});


function updateTxt(field,toField){
    var field = document.getElementById(field);
    var toField = document.getElementById(toField);
    toField.innerHTML=field.value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should **NOT** use the id attribute when you are using it more than once. there may be only one id with the same value within the page!

if you want to remove an upper element selecting it by its child you can use the `:has()` selector.

```
$("p:has(#txt2)").remove();
```

So lets begin again :)

```
$('#addParty').live('click', function() {
    $('<p><a href="#" data-party-id="'+i+'" id="remParty">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(partyDiv);
    $('<p><span data-party-id="'+i+'"></span></p>').appendTo(textDiv);
});
```

I do assing `data-party-id` to *both* elements, as we can later easily refer to them.

Now lets do the magic to remove it.

```
$('.remParty').live('click', function() { 
    // learn something about data attributes and data()
    var partyId = $(this).data("party-id");
    $('p:has([data-party-id="' + partyId + '"])').remove();
});
```

But it would be much easier, if you would assign the identification to the `p` and not to the span. Then you do not need the `:has()` selector

Comment: what the ...? please elaborate why downvoting this answer

Comment: I didnt downvote. But I dont really understand how this answer solves my problem. I dont want to remove the closest element, I want to remove the `span id=txt2` and its parent `<p>` when I click the remove link for `input id="party_2"` (see edited post)

Comment: ok, maybe i missundertood you before. i updated my answer, are we now thinking the same?

Comment: yes that works! the problem is that i need to be able to remove any of the fields that have been generated, so using `#txt2` only removes the second txt element. I need to remove the txt that corresponds with the created field above. So when i remove the fourth field, the fourth txt is removed, etc.

Comment: came up with a not so pretty solution.. :P